# Performance problems using QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>>

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I am having serious performance issues using a `QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>>` instance.

Let's say I have a class `EmojiList` which does nothing but to hold this vector which is being filled with about 4000 emojis and their respective shortname and category:

**emojilist.h**

```cpp
#include <QVector>

class EmojiList {
public:
    static const QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>>& list() {
        static EmojiList list;

        return list.emojiList;
    }

private:
    QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>> emojiList {
        { { "‍‍‍", ":woman_woman_girl_girl:" }, "People & Body" },
        { { "‍‍‍", ":woman_woman_girl_boy:" }, "People & Body" },
        { { "‍‍‍", ":woman_woman_boy_boy:" }, "People & Body" },
        { { "‍‍‍", ":man_woman_girl_girl:" }, "People & Body" },
        { { "‍‍‍", ":man_woman_girl_boy:" }, "People & Body" },
        // ... ~ 4000 entries to come
    };
```

It's being referenced (*not* copied) two times in other classes and queried directly on construction in a `QAbstractListModel` subclass:

**emojilistmodel.h**

```cpp
#include "emojilist.h"

class EmojiListModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // ...

private:
    const QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>>& _emojiMap { EmojiList::list() };
```

When compiling my application including `emojilist.h`, compiling takes about **1:20min**, without `emojilist.h`, it takes 3.8 seconds.

Also, starting the application takes heavily longer than when leaving out `emojilist.h`: startup time without `emojilist.h` included is 4 seconds, startup time including `emojilist.h` is **3:40min**.

**How can I optimize my code for performance and speed here? Should I use a different class than `QVector` or should I maybe switch to a `QMap` or a different type of container?**

Maybe also using a Singleton in this case wouldn't be that much of a good idea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are [obsessed with primitives](https://testing.googleblog.com/2017/11/obsessed-with-primitives.html)

Comment: Aside: why is this a class? `extern QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>> emojiList;` in emojilist.h, and then `QVector<QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>> emojiList { ... }` in emojilist.cpp *should* help (at least) the compile time

Comment: There is quite a lot potential for optimizations. 
1) Put the static variable from private class member to inside of the `list()` function and define it in `cpp` file! Then it will be created upon the first `list()` use and not upon startup.
2) Use `QStringLiteral` which will save lots of allocations and coonversions.
3) How about using a `struct` with named fields instead of `QPair<QPair<QString, QString>, QString>`... I am not sure if this would result in performance improvement, but the code would be nicer.
Please let us know how these changes improved compile times and run times...

Comment: I'd also recommend moving this list out of the code and into e.g. [a resource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: Keeping 4000 lines of data in a header file is a bad idea; if nothing else, move all of that into the .cpp file so that it doesn't have to be re-parsed every time some other file has a `#include "emojilist.h"`

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile thanks for the hints, however `QStringLiteral` doesn't seem to work since Qt Creator complains about an unknown type and that `QLatin1Literal` was deprecated. I tried using `QStringView` it's not suitable to convert to `QVariant`.

Comment: @taiBsu Could you show the code where `QStringLiteral` did not work for you? This is not possible. You must have done some mistake... Btw. `QStringView` is something completely different, it makes no use in your case.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile sorry, took me some time to find out that `QStringLiteral` is just a macro and not a type. Looks like I'll read the emojis including shortname and category from a resource file and pass them as references into a struct that saves `QString`s.

Comment: @taiBsu It is a pity you decided for a different solution, I was curious how much faster it would be if you used my suggestions :) Is this your file with emojis secret and private? Or could you share it using for example pastebin.com? I would try to optimize that myself to see the results.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile I would have liked to use your solution, however I decided to follow @Caleth s approach to use a resource file, thus I parse line by line using a `QStringList` which is the result of the line being split with `,`. The content is then being saved as QString in a structure. I'll post the code as soon as I have a performance result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reduce the compile time to 3 seconds by outsourcing the emoji list parsing into the `.cpp` file:

**emojilist.h**

```cpp
#include <QVector>

class EmojiList {
public:

    struct EmojiData {
        EmojiData(const QString& _code, const QString& _shortname, const QString& _category) :
            code(_code),
            shortname(_shortname),
            category(_category)
        {}

        QString code;
        QString shortname;
        QString category;
    };

    static const QVector<EmojiData>& list();

private:
    QVector<EmojiData> emojiList;

    void parseFromFile();
};
```

**emojilist.cpp**

```cpp
#include "emojilist.h"

#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

const QVector<EmojiList::EmojiData>& EmojiList::list()
{
    static EmojiList list;

    if (list.emojiList.isEmpty()) {
        list.parseFromFile();
    }

    return list.emojiList;
}

void EmojiList::parseFromFile()
{
    QFile emojiResource { ":/media/new_emoji.list" };

    if (emojiResource.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream in { &emojiResource };

        while (!in.atEnd()) {
            QStringList line { in.readLine().split(',') };
            emojiList.append({ line.at(0), line.at(1), line.at(2) });
        }
    }

    emojiResource.close();
}
```

It is then being retrieved in my list model:

**emojilistmodel.cpp**

```cpp
QVariant EmojiListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (_emojiMap.isEmpty() || !index.isValid() || index.row() > _emojiMap.size()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    switch (role) {
    case EmojiName:
        return _emojiMap.at(index.row()).shortname;
    case Emoji:
        return _emojiMap.at(index.row()).code;
    case EmojiCategory: {
        return _emojiMap.at(index.row()).category;
    }
    default:
        return QVariant();
    }
}
```

It works quite well, **however** startup still takes incredibly long (5+ minutes). Anyways, this seems to be a **QML-related problem** so I'll have to create an extra issue for that.

Thanks a lot everyone for helping so far.